# Salesforce Angular JS and Governor Limit

Tags: angularjs, salesforce

I have utilized angular JS in visualforce page aling with apex class to make a enhance dynamic search of transaction data in salesforce. The way it is done now is the following.

1) Apex Class executes a SOQL which returns a JSON string of data elements.
2) Visual force page which incorporates angular JS shows the data, with a search box on top.

## Problem:

Some of the objects is returning more than 50000 rows, and governor limit exception is thrown.

## Question:

How can I invoke to get chunks of 100 records, the user will search from that 100 records, if the search data do not exist, then "Show More" button will retrieve the next 100 records.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this is really angular or salesforce specific, try to implement some sort of pagination and filtering/ordering mechanism.